# What's the name of this old mid 90's thriller/supernatural/gore hollywood movie?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Okay, so the movie starts out with a group of US Special Forces Team and two high Government looking persons being dispatched somewhere in the South/Central America to rescue some high ranking official who is being held as a Hostage by the Insurgents over there. And the main protagonist is also one of the soldier in the US Special Forces Team that is part of this operation. The main protagonist and the rest of the Special Forces Team decide to strike the main base of the Insurgence, where the High ranking offical is also being held as a hostage, at dusk. But, when they finally make it to the Insurgence main base/camp it's all empty and dead silent. And as they move in closer to the base to they are also shocked to see that all the Insurgents and the Hostage have been killed. To be more specific all the bodies are found slaughtered. Actually, the scene had a lot of Gore. As they show body parts like intestine, limbs, eye sockets being empty and all that. And also there was a lot of blood all over the main base. They then look to find if there were any surviors but they don't find any survivors. So, they head back to the Rendezvous Point or RV for extraction. They do reach the extraction point but it would take about 4 or 5 hours for the Helicopters to arrive and pick them up or something like that. So, the soldiers decide to rest up and wait till their pickup arrives as it was late in the night. But, after an hour or so suddenly a soldier starts to scream as he starts to levitate in the air to everyones suprise. Then he starts screaming out even more loud as it seems some unknown entity is pulling out his arms and legs. And they do come out with blood squirting out from his arms and legs to everyone's horror. He then dies. And then quickly a few other soldiers also start to cry out in agony as some unknown entity starts to torment them and kill them. Out of fear and panic everyone starts to fire around. The remaining soldiers then stop firing around as the killings stops. Eventually, only the 2 government agents, the main protagonist, main protagonist friend and 3 other soldiers are the only ones to survive. There is blood everywhere and body parts of their dead commarades all over the ground. We then hear and see to helicopters approaching.

The scene then skips about a week later. The two government agents once rescued later inform the remaining surviving soldiers to not disclose the events that have transpired. And they are also informed that they will be monitored at all times in order to keep this information from being disclosed. But, later we learn that the main protagonist friend has killed the agents who were monitoring him and has stolen the video footages of their operation in the south/central america and has gone of the surface. The main protagonist is ordered and threatened by the two government agents and a lot of higher ups in the government to find his friend and kill him because they fear that word might spread and can lead to chaos.

Thats all I remember. I want to complete this movie. Pleas help in finding the name of this english/hollywood film. I don't know the actors name because I think they are not that big or they are old 90's actors.

Comment: It's surprising the level of detail that you can recall.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be [Predator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093773/)

> A team of special force ops, led by a tough but fair soldier, Major "Dutch" Schaefer, are ordered in to assist CIA man, George Dillon, on a rescue mission for potential survivors of a Helicopter downed over remote South American jungle. Not long after they land, Dutch and his team discover that they have been sent in under false pretenses. This deception turns out to be the least of their worries though, when they find themselves being methodically hunted by something not of this world.

The movie fits your loose plot description even thought the estimated date is wrong. The are special forces ops.. not really government agents. The reason they are in the jungle and the events that transpire there is accurate.

There were several notable actors in the movie. Most well know would be Arnold Schwarzenegger. Arnold's character spends most of the movie trying to get to da choppa

Comment: I am checking now as the later details of the movie that start to seem odd to me from the OP description. I am having issues remembering the end after the final showdown.

Comment: The plot sounds more like *Predator 2*, the governement agents could be the DEA, one of them played by Gary Busey. However, I don't remember the sequel taking place in south america. Could it be possible you've mixed the two movies together?